# Spring Tool Suite how to upgrade Grails to 2.2

Tags: grails, spring-tool-suite

I am using STS Version: 3.2.0.RELEASE, it comes with Grails 2.1.1. I would like to upgrade it to Grails 2.2.

when I select check update its says upto date. but not upgrading Grails. what is process to upgrade grails, groovy and embded tomcat to last version?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Grails from the website, unpack in the desired location and point it in: `Window > Preferences > Grails` (look [here](http://www.grails.org/STS+Integration), in "versions of groovy and grails).